# display all and only direct children of a category

Tags: category

Say I have the following category and product structure:

```
    1. Category
        a. Subcategory
           i. Product
           ii. Product
        b. Subcategory
           i. Product
        c. Product
        d. Product
```

When viewing the category page, I want to show all and only its direct children. So, for this example, I would want to list a, b, c & d (but not a i., a ii., etc.).

I'm pretty new at Magento, so I'm having trouble stitching together a view that does what I want it to. So far, I have this:

```
<?php
$category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$categories = $category->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
?>
<ul class="thumbnails featured category">
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
        <li class="span 2">
            <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog' . DS . 'category' . DS . $category->getThumbnail() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>" />
                    <h5><?php echo $category->getName() ?></h5>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

This will display the subcategories, but it won't display the products, if they are direct children. I don't really understand `Magento's` syntax yet, so I don't quite know what I'm doing here (I copied, adopted, and pasted this from elsewhere on the web).

Is there a way to generalize this list item to display the product thumbnail and url, if it's a direct child? Or, perhaps to create another list item that displays the product, on the condition that the direct child is a product, and not a subcategory?

Answer (score 2):

To get the direct children of a category `getChildern()` function is there. It will return id of all direct children as string.

```
$category->getChildren();//this will return 2,3,4,5 (for example)
```

Then use `php -> explode()` function to get all these id as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Add this after your subcategory display and adjust the `classes/display` as you wish.

```
<?php $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addCategoryFilter($category)
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail', 'url_key'))
?>
<ul class="thumbnails featured product">
    <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
        <li class="span 2">
            <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($product->getName()) ?>" />
                    <h5><?php echo $product->getName() ?></h5>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: That works at displaying the products, but it displays them regardless of whether they are a direct child or not. I only want to display the products if they are a direct child of the category (not if they are the child of a subcategory within the category being displayed).